# When does a cut require medical attention?

Tags: bleeding, abrasion-cut-laceration

Here is a brief scenario from my actual experience:

Someone cuts their finger on a sharp knife and the cut is a bit deep. With pressure the bleeding eventually stops, and the small flap of skin that was partially cut is covering the wound entirely. However, there is a small amount of blood under the small flap of skin.

Does this injury require medical attention?

Comment: When you say "medical attention," do you mean first aid, or professional medical attention in the form of urgent care or hospital emergency room? I'm sure any medical professional would tell you that any wound that breaks the skin, and thus causes bleeding, requires first aid at a bare minimum.

Comment: Any opening into the skin regardless of its size can create a potential source for bacteria to enter the body, which can increase the chance of infection. It is advisable that you consult with your primary care physician to receive a proper assessment.